# Issue with hidden input and very large values in HTML and ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Since there appears to be a 1024 character limit for hidden input values, what does everyone do for values in excess of this limit? Can a hidden file input (<input type="file" value="some very long value"...) be reasonably used instead? What would the field length restrictions be of any such solution?

```
<input id="someId" type="hidden" 
value="5538680,5538683,5538858,5539195,5540063,5540812,5540814,5541665,5541666,5541667,
5541668,5541669,5541670,5541671,5541672,5541673,5541674,5541675,5541676,5541677,5541678,
5541679,5541680,5541682,5541683,5541684,5541685,5541686,5541687,5541688,5541689,5541690,
5541691,5541692,5541693,5541694,5541695,5541696,5541697,5541698,5541728,5543254,5543501,
5543502,5543949,5543950,5544073,5544867,5545079,5545642,5545827,5545890,5545891,5545895,
5545896,5546323,5546631,5546632,5546972,5547794,5547900,5547945,5547980,554923...735181,
5735182,5735183,5735184,5735185,5735187,5735188,5735189,5735227,5735228,5735229,5735235,
5735236,5735237,5735238,5735239,5735240,5735241,5735242,5735243,5735273,5735744,5735745,
5735746,5735747,5735748,5735749,5735836,5735837,5735838,5735839,5735840,5735841,5735842,
5735843,5735844,5735845,5735846,5735847,5735848,5735849,5735850,5735851,5735852,5735853,
5735854,5735855,5735856,5735857,5735858,5735859,5737183,5738250,5738563,5738564,5738565,
5738566,5738567,5738568,5738569,5738570,5738731,5738732,5738946" name="someName">
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, and would appreciate a solution that could integrate with a minimum of effort. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass model values in excess of 1024 characters with razor syntax.

I also need to be able to manipulate the value client-side, using JavaScript/jQuery.

What does everyone do to get around this issue?
Ideally, I'd like to deal with the value as a single variable. Is there a good way to handle such information? The largest value for my usage appears to be about 40k in size.

Edit: If you note the ... in the value of the input element above, it appears that the value is being shortened to 1024 characters, to fit into the value attribute. I'm not positive of the cause of this issue, but believe it to be a limit on the attribute size. If someone can deny this, and/or explain how to allow for a larger attribute or field somewhere, I would greatly appreciate it. I would prefer keeping the re-factoring to a minimum, as I already have a significant investment in the current architecture. A number of other components currently utilize this list of values in it's current form.

Edit: My mistake! Firebug was reporting the "...", and causing JavaScript errors. It apparently doesn't handle attributes in excess of 1024 characters well. All of the data is in fact populating without issue (when firebug is disabled). This appears to be an issue with firebug. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I believe you should re-think your architecture if you need 40K long input boxes.. Care to share the concept behind this need ?

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is on hidden inputs?  I know there is an issue with QueryString size limit in .Net4 being 1024, not having anything to do with MVC.  It can be configured in web.config

Comment: Adding the following to the web.config doesn't appear to have any effect:
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="16384" />
    ...
</system.web>

Comment: Gaby, I'm using the field to store the IDs of a set of models related to the model currently being edited. In almost all cases, this field contains less than 200 characters. There are a few outliers that contain a much larger list. Only 19 out of several thousand have more than 1000 characters, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the grouping

```
<input name="someIDs[0]" type="hidden" value="5538680"/>
<input name="someIDs[1]" type="hidden" value="5538683/>
```

**update:**

controllers

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(rand.Next(1,999999));
        }
        return View(list);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(int[] item)
    {
        return View(item.ToList());
    }
```

view

```
@model List<int>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (int item in Model)
    {

        <input type="hidden" name="item" value="@item" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Since I don't know where the limit comes from, you could also try <input name="someIDs" id="someIDs_0" type="hidden" value="5538680"/>
<input name="someIDs" id="someIDs_1" type="hidden" value="5538683/> Each html element is small, but when it posts across would be read as all the someIDs value comma separated

Comment: While the problem didn't exist, I'm marking this as the answer, since it's more cleanly than my solution.

Answer (score 5):

How about a

```
<textarea name="someName">5538680,5538683,...</textarea>
```

with a style/css rule of `display:none` applied to it ?

Answer (score 0):

1024 is the limit of any attribute on an HTML element in HTML 3 and below.  To get around it, you could use a text area where you put the value in between the tags.

Since you have so much data, you might be better off implementing some sort of paging on the server side and using AJAX to make a request to get the next set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most "correct" way to do this would be using data attributes.

```
#my-info {
    display: none;
}

<div id="my-info" data-ids="id1,id2,etc"></div>
```

Or through javascript:

```
<script>
    $("#my-info").data("ids", @Model.JsonIds);
</script>
```

And have `Model.JsonIds` populated with a Json string.

I would personally go with the second, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gaby about re-thinking the architecture. But if you really must, I suggest you build up javascript array. That way it will be much easier to work with data. it is pretty simple to do this with razor.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really think there is a limit. so long as you can get your string length between the " " quotes, and on the same line, it should accept it. there's rumours of it being 65000 characters, however someone wrote a javascript and got it well over 2,000,000 characters.

Comment: This should be comment