# MVC Razor view 'System.OutOfMemoryException' with large value string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a big JSON object which I need to pass to the view displayed in web browser. Since I can not have a Controller with an Action to return this JSON object, I thought to add the JSON object in the Razor view.

1. `@Html.Hidden("fileContent", fileContent);`
2. `<textarea  style="display:none">
       @fileContent
    </textarea>`

None of the above works as the ways I expected and gives me,

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Yes, I agreed that's better to restructure the flow in another way ([may be as Mediator suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287153/issue-with-hidden-input-and-very-large-values-in-html-and-asp-net-mvc-3-razor/10287557#10287557) or have an action to return the JSON object.)

1. Is that a limitation of MVC, the maximum size we can have for a MVC view?
2. Is this because of the IIS Express configuration?
3. Any other way to overcome this issue? Or the best way to pass a large object to the client browser.

Thank you for your time. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

*Controller*

```
var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/content/data.csv"));
ViewData.Add("file", file);
return View();
```

*Stack trace*

> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   was thrown.]    System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32
>   minBlockCharCount) +163    System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char*
>   value, Int32 valueCount) +82
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendHelper(String value) +31
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value) +186
>   System.IO.StringWriter.Write(String value) +30
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(Object value) +87

Comment: What is `fileContent`? And what is the point of sending it to the view and then sending it back again unchanged?

Comment: There are many factors causing `OutOfMemoryException`, e.g. `StringBuilder` overflow or lack of memory allocation for certain thread. Check controller code to make sure resource allocations are handled properly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the fileContent is a JSON string. I convert that string into JSON object in the client side java script. This JSON object will use to render the page.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto You're correct. I have added the stack trace and the controller code. I didn't use any resource allocation. 

Did you mean something like run the garbage collector or so?

Could you please share a link regarding that or any tips to how to do that?

Comment: How big is `data.csv`?

Comment: Better to use `ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/content/data.csv"))` or `ReadLines` since it reads a line at a time as `IEnumerable<String>`, hence less memory cost than loading all text into an array string passed for `ViewData`. Read this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965497/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readalllines-and-file-readalltext.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev It is getting bigger. At the moment it is nearly 1.5 MB

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you. Is there any other things I can do with resource allocation? And after I retrieve the list from _viewdata_ shouldn't I have to combine them again, to pass that as a single value or the content

Comment: Considering the file size is more than 1 MB, and array of chars should be contiguous, it may be achieved by using separate iterations with combining afterwards other than storing all at once in memory (and be wise calling `GC.Collect()` to clean up memory after dealing with large size objects).

Comment: The problem appears to be that Razor can't allocate enough contiguous memory to create a 1.5 MB array (probably 3 MB due to UTF-16, and probably 4 MB due to the expanding of the StringBuilder's internal array). This is an awful little amount of memory to throw this exception. Try using a string array of lines instead and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster I quite agree with you, but this _StringBuilder_ and the _StringWriter_ use inside MVC (_System.Web.WebPages_), so how we suppose to manage this. By the way, could you please explain me, what you mean by using string array of lines?

Comment: Instead of reading the file into one string, read it into a string array and write that in a loop. Though this may not make a difference, because it's the view's StringBuilder throwing the exception.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah it is working. But seems there is no other way to send that object at once inside a DOM element. Isn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your CSV file size, better to use `ReadLines` than `ReadAllText` like below:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Capacity = 16; // default, adjust it to less number as you wish

foreach (String line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/content/data.csv")))
{
    sb.Append(line);    
}

ViewData.Add("file", sb.ToString());
```

`ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<String>` that reads a file line by line (one line at a time), hence it is suitable for certain files which potentially consuming huge memory space when stored as single large string.

However, if file contents are extremely large, consider using `StreamReader` instead of `StringBuilder` which requires contiguous array size and depends on [heap fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733667/memory-free-up-string-builder-an-d-byte-in-c-out-of-memory-exception):

```
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/content/data.csv")))
{
     String line;
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         // combine source strings here
     }
}
```

Note that each character requires 2 bytes, and strings are array of characters, thus there should be contiguous arrays which affects performance and size during generating objects in memory. Hence, optimizing garbage collector functionality with `GC.Collect()` method may helpful after dealing with huge amount of objects requiring immediate cleanup.

Related references:

[interesting OutOfMemoryException with StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769447/interesting-outofmemoryexception-with-stringbuilder)

[MSDN: System.Text.StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

[MSDN: System.IO.StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader)

[Eric Lippert: Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)

Comment: The reading is not the problem, the writing onto the view is.

Comment: Thank you for passing valuable tips. File reads successfully to the variable. (into _ViewData_), error occurs once it try to render the DOM element with that value.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but my idea was to split JSON strings by each line into several hidden fields after executing `ReadLines` which passed array of strings e.g. `@for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++) { @Html.Hidden("fileContent" + i, file[i]); }` due to possible limitations in hidden field value rendered by HTML.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto It is working. It should because Razor doesn't use the lengthy value. But again I have to combine those strings into one in the java script which also can cause the lag. Seems that's is a limitation of the Razor engine, isn't it?

Comment: I think it isn't limitation from Razor engine, it may comes from HTML specification which limits value in hidden field at certain amount of characters. I will edit the answer above after all things were confirmed.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto That is not only for the hidden fields, it happens even you try to have this content inside the DIV. I think that happen when Razor tries to build the view result.